# Get value of config/session in Laravel global middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to retrieve values from Config or Session variable in a Laravel-7 Global Middleware but it is not working.  The values are set in the Login Controller.
I tried

```
info(Config::get("database.connections.mysql.userdb","nil"));
info(Session::get("selected_database"));
```

Can someone help how I can get values from config or session or any other global variable in a Global Middleware.  The value needs to be set once upon login and used in Global Middleware on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Moving StartSession from MiddlewareGroup to Middleware in the Kernal.php solved the problem.  But I am not sure if this is the correct way.  Can anyone elaborate.
Here is the Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,   //moved from middlewareGroups
    \App\Http\Middleware\SelectDB::class,

    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I want to work with session in middleware. The problem was I added my middleware into $middleware in kernel.

But finally I figured out that Sessions are not accessible in $middleware, you must add your middlewares into $middlewareGroups inside 'web' key.

Answer (score -1):

you can set session like following way :
if use Session class, import it from :
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

or

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

and get the session like following way :

```
$value = Session::get('key');
```

or

```
$value = session('key');
```

I hope be useful

Comment: I thing the 2nd one is Session::get('key).  Already tried this one, I get an empty value.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed if use Session class add this line `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`

Comment: Still blank result with "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;"  The reason i think is session is not started yet.  Mine is a global middleware defined in Middleware Section of Kernal.php, whereas startsession is defined in middlewareGoup

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed please add your kernel protected middleware array